# Horner algorithm implementation in c++

Tags: c++

Implement the Horner algorithm for determining the value of the polynomial. Input data should be given as program parameters: polynomial coefficients and value.

Below is an example call:
/horner 1.0 2.2 -3.3 7.0

-145.3

counts the value of W (7.0), where W (x) = 1.0 + 2.2x ^ 1-3.3x ^ 2

Turn this:

```cpp
double Horner(int n, double A[], double x0)
{
  double w;

  w = A[n];
  for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    w = w * x0 + A[i];
  return w;
}
```

Into code with pointers and char so it looks like the task example.
Stuck at  `w=A[n];` and idk if the code is going in the right direction.
What I got so far:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int n = argc - 3;
  double x0 = atof(argv[argc - 1]);
  double *A = new double[n + 1];

  for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
  {
    A[i] = atof(argv[i + 1]);
  }
  double w;
  w=A[n]; 
  for(int k =n; k>=0; k=k-1) {
    w=w*x0+A[k];
  }
  cout << w;
  delete[] A;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do not want `int k =n-k;` k on the right side. Apart from what, I do not see much wrong. What is your question exactly?

Comment: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_array_new_length'` also its  `int k=n` only?

Comment: `int n = argc - 3;` did you pass 4 arguments when you ran the program from the command line? You probably want to print an error and exit the program if n is less than 1.

Comment: @debooger3 That seems like an important thing to include in the question. Run it through the debugger and see what causes it. Yep, `k=n` should be fine, where does `n-3` come from?

Comment: Tried running it, getting `-1277.2` instead `-145.3`, -3 needs to be there, told by our teacher. Also without it, im getting `segmentation fault core dumped`

Comment: I think it's `polynomial to the power of n-3`

Comment: @Quimby If the command line is `/horner 1.0 2.2 -3.3 7.0`, then `argc` is 5, removing the program name and the last value (x), we are left with the *three* coefficients of a *second* degree polynomial. In short, `n = argc - 3`. Not that I'm endorsing those kind of unsafe "tricks", to be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming to call the function in the first snippet with the parameters `n = 2`, `A[] = {1.0, 2.2, -3.3}` and `x0 = 7.0`, if we would track its execution, we'd find:

```
w = A[n] = A[2] = -3.3
i = n - 1 = 1  // <----- Note this.
w = w * x0 + A[1] = -3.3 * 7.0 + 2.2 = -20.9
w = w * x0 + A[0] = -20.9 * 7.0 + 1.0 = 145.3
```

In the second snippet, though, the idices are off by one.

```
int n = argc - 3;
```

Let's assume that the command line is `/horner 1.0 2.2 -3.3 7.0`, as mentioned by the OP, where the last number represent `x0` and the other numbers are the coefficients of the polynomial. That formula gives the correct value for its degree (2, in a perfect world, where the users always type the correct number of values in the exact needed order).

The cofficients and `w` are correctly initialized, but then, the following loop starts from the wrong index (it should have skipped the last one, already used to initialize `w`).

```
for( int k = n; k >= 0; k = k - 1) {
//       ^^^^^
    w = w * x0 + A[k];
}
```